# Insert scripts into an existing function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function is built into the page and I cannot modify the original .js file:

```
cool.lol = function () {

    // contents here

}
```

Is there a way for me to append this function with some of my own scripts?

Like this:

```
cool.lol = function () {

    // contents here

    // i would like to add my own stuff here!!!
}
```

Or is there a way for me to detect that the function has been executed so I can run something after it?

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/tell-jquery-to-trigger-function-after-another-function-is-run-or-completed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here's a demo of the following](http://jsfiddle.net/FGeUu/4/). Updated to use a closure and remove the need for a temporary variable.

```
//your cool with lol
var cool = {
    lol: function() {
        alert('lol');
    }
}

//let's have a closure that carries the original cool.lol
//and returns our new function with additional stuff

cool.lol = (function(temp) { //cool.lol is now the local temp
    return function(){       //return our new function carrying the old cool.lol
        temp.call(cool);     //execute the old cool.lol
        alert('bar');        //additional stuff
    }
}(cool.lol));                //pass in our original cool.lol

cool.lol();
cool.lol();​
```

Comment: Nice touch with the anonymous function.  The only caveat here, obviously, is that you cannot access variables within `cool.lol`'s original namespace.

Comment: @cheeken hmm, nice spot. i'll try testing other ways. having a temp variable lying around is not good, especially [when it's accidentally nulled](http://jsfiddle.net/FGeUu/3/).

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - Why don't you use `.call()` to refer back `this`?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Pcxn5/1/

```
// original definition which you can't touch
var cool = {
    lol: function() {
        alert("test");
    }
}
//

// your script
var ori = cool.lol;
cool.lol = function() {
    ori();
    alert('my test');
}

cool.lol();​
```

Comment: If same answer was indeed the reason then why is it that even though mine was the second, the third didn't get downvoted (sigh) :( sorry ranting a bit there... Thanks anyway @Derek :)

Comment: @NiftyDude some people just hit and run with downvotes for no reason. Anyways, I upvote in response to that downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the function:

```
// The file you can't touch has something like this
var cool = {};
cool.lol = function () {
    console.log("original");
}

// Keep a copy of the original function.
// Override the original and execute the copy inside
var original = cool.lol;
cool.lol = function () {
    original();
    console.log("modified");
}

// Call
cool.lol();​ // logs "original", then "modified".
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K8SLH/

Answer (score 1):

Without creating variables polluting the public scope:

```
 //let's have your cool namespace
var cool = {
    lol: function() {
        alert('lol');
    }
}

//temporarily store
cool.lol_original = cool.lol;

//overwrite
cool.lol = function() {
    this.lol_original(); //call the original function
    alert('bar');    //do some additional stuff
}

cool.lol();​
```

Comment: Try @Joseph the Dreamer 's answer, it is definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript allows you to

- get the code of the functions as a string
- create new functions by supplying a string with code

Every object has a `toString()` method. For functions, it returns their code (unless overriden).

```
cool.lol.toString();
```

returns `function() { // contents here }`.

Let us extract the body of the function from this string. It starts immediately after `{` and includes everything except the last `}`.

```
var code = cool.lol.toString();
var body = code.substring(code.indexOf('{') + 1, code.length - 1);
```

Then we add more stuff

```
var newBody = body + '// i would like to add my own stuff here!!!';
```

and create a new function using the `Function` constructor.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

```
cool.lol = new Function(newBody);
```

Of course, there is more work to do if the new function also has to retain arguments (you have to parse them out from the function code, then give them as parameters to the `Function` constructor). For simplicity, in this case I assumed there are no arguments to the function.

An example implementation:

http://jsfiddle.net/QA9Zx/

Comment: It's better to avoid using the Function constructor. It's `eval`'s twin.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Yes, I understand the string passed to `Function` must be eval-ed. And in practice, I would not use this approach. However, my solution is the only one that *actually* inserted a script into an existing function in the strict sense :-p I am just proposing this as an alternative solution to wrapping the function by another, as suggested by other respondents.

Comment: fair enough. the more solutions, the better :)

Comment: @Imp if you wouldn't actually to it that way, I'd at least mention that, and the reasons why, in your answer. While this is an interesting trick, I would be sad to see it in production code anywhere.